# Remove posts inside pre_get_posts using a custom query

Tags: filters, sql, pre-get-posts

I need to remove posts from admin listing, if their last child post author is different than the parent post author.

I was hoping to use `pre_get_posts`, but can't figure out how to do this. Here's my code so far:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'ooo_admin_tickets_filter');
function ooo_admin_tickets_filter($query)
{
   global $wpdb, $pagenow,$post;
   if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_GET['test']  == 'yes' ) {

  // get last child - using a custom query, because for some reason I was unable to use WP_Query or get_posts inside pre_get_post filter

  $latest = $wpdb->get_var("
            SELECT post_author FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_parent = '$post->ID'
            AND post_type = 'reply'
            AND post_status = 'inherit'
            ORDER BY post_date DESC
            LIMIT 1
            ");

        if( empty( $latest ) || $latest != $post->post_author) {
            $query->set('post__not_in',array($post->ID));
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: if you're on the list of posts in admin, what is `$post` supposed to contain? also- using `WP_Query` or `get_posts` in a `pre_get_posts` filter is tricky, since they both trigger the very filter you are currently querying within, you have to be careful not to create an infinite loop.

Comment: Yup, exactly - what is than the way do remove the posts based on my custom query?